# Metodo serialize() do jQuery não funcionando

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um modal com alguns campos no qual faço uma chamada AJAX para tratamento dos dados, mas o problema é quando o jQuery vai serializar os inputs do meu form. Simplesmente não funciona.

Abaixo meu modal:

```
<!-- Modal de Destinos-->
<div class="modal fade" id="destinationModal" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="destination-modal-form"
                action="./addSelectedDestination" method="post">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Negociar Novo
                        Destino</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div id="div-modal-input-body-destination"
                        class="aling-form col-sm-12 nest text"
                        style="padding-top: 25px">

                        <div class="box01">
                            <select id="destination-passenger-list" class="form-control" name="${customerService.serviceItem.destination}">
                                <c:forEach items="${destinationList}" var="destination">
                                    <option value="${destination.idDestination}">${destination.dtName}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="box02">
                            <div class="input-group skin skin-flat">
                                <input id="ckb-requested" type="checkbox" name="${customerService.serviceItem.requestedDestination}" /> <label
                                    id="ckb-label" for="ckb-requested">Destino
                                    Solicitado pelo Passageiro?</label>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="box01">
                            <div class="input-group ">
                                <span id="span-departure"
                                    class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i
                                    class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span> <input id="input-departure"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="${customerService.serviceItem.departureDate}"
                                    class="form-control" placeholder="Data de Ida" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="box02">
                            <div class="input-group ">
                                <span id="span-arrive" class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i
                                    class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span> <input id="input-arrive"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="${customerService.serviceItem.arrivalDate}"
                                    class="form-control" placeholder="Data de Volta" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="box01">
                            <select class="form-control" name="${customerService.serviceItem.saleType}">
                                <c:forEach items="${listOfSaleTypes}" var="saleType">
                                    <option value="${saleType.key}">${saleType.value}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="box02">
                            <div class="input-group ">
                                <span
                                    class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i
                                    class="fa fa-money"></i></span> <input id="input-price"
                                    type="text" data-thousands="." data-decimal=","
                                    name="${customerService.serviceItem.valueNegotiated}"
                                    class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="box03">
                            <textarea id="destination-observations" name="${customerService.serviceItem.negociationObservations}" rows="3" placeholder="Observações..." class="form-control"
                                style="min-height: 130px;"></textarea>
                        </div>


                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer clear" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button id="button-add-destination" type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Chamada AJAX:

```
$('#destination-modal-form').submit( function(e){

   var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/addSelectedDestination";
   var formdata = $(this).serialize();

   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data: formdata,
    url: url,
    success: function(jsonData){
        alert("Sucesso!!!.");
    }, 
    error: function(error){
        alert("Erro: Tente Novamente preenchendo todos os campos, ou entre em contato com o administrador do sistema.");
    }
   });
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Está aparecendo algum erro no console? Qual o resultado do `serialize()`? Uma string vazia?

Comment: @Lucas, não apresenta nenhum erro no console. A unica coisa que o serialize me retorna é o parametro dentro de `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />`

Comment: Coloca o  e.preventDefault(); logo abaixo da declaração da função, acima da declaração da variável url e testa.

Comment: Consegui pôr isto a funcionar? O código funciona bem no jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/z1x67dv8/

Comment: voce tem certeza que os atributos "name" dos outros "inputs" estão recebendo os valores passados? será que não estão nulos? Pois todo o resto está correto o problema deve ser nos parametros passados pelo java

Comment: Qual a sua versão do jquery?

Comment: Outra forma de se fazer o serialize seria colocar var data = new FormData($(this)); testa desta forma

Answer (score 1):

Possivelmente o problema seja com o código Java pois alterei os name's para demonstrar o funcionamento do serialize();

- Alterei o type do botão de: "submit" para "button"
- Alterei a chamada da função de: $('#destination-modal-form') - para $('#button-add-destination')
- Comentei o código Ajax e coloquei um alert no serialize().

obs: Testei no meu ambiente Java e os name's foram atribuidos dinâmicamente 
 permitindo o serialize(), verifique se está ocorrendo dessa forma no seu código.

```js
$(function(){
 $('#button-add-destination').click( function(e){

 var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/addSelectedDestination";
 var formdata = $('#destination-modal-form').serialize();
 alert(formdata);
 /*
 $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  data: formdata,
  url: url,
  success: function(jsonData){
  alert("Sucesso!!!.");
  }, 
  error: function(error){
   alert("Erro: Tente Novamente preenchendo todos os campos, ou entre em contato com o administrador do sistema.");
  }
 });
 e.preventDefault();
 */
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal de Destinos-->
 <div class="modal fade" id="destinationModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

   <div class="modal-content">
    <form id="destination-modal-form"
     action="./addSelectedDestination" method="post">

     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Negociar Novo
       Destino</h4>
     </div>

     <div class="modal-body">

      <div id="div-modal-input-body-destination"
       class="aling-form col-sm-12 nest text"
       style="padding-top: 25px">

       <div class="box01">
        <select id="destination-passenger-list" class="form-control" name="destination">
         <option value="1">A</option>
         <option value="2">B</option>
         <option value="3">C</option>
        </select>
       </div>

       <div class="box02">
        <div class="input-group skin skin-flat">
         <input id="ckb-requested" type="checkbox" name="requestedDestination" /> <label
          id="ckb-label" for="ckb-requested">Destino
          Solicitado pelo Passageiro?</label>

        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="box01">
        <div class="input-group ">
         <span id="span-departure"
          class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i
          class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span> <input id="input-departure"
          type="text"
          name="departureDate"
          class="form-control" placeholder="Data de Ida" />
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="box02">
        <div class="input-group ">
         <span id="span-arrive" class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i
          class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span> <input id="input-arrive"
          type="text"
          name="arrivalDate"
          class="form-control" placeholder="Data de Volta" />
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="box01">
        <select class="form-control" name="saleType">
         <option value="1">T</option>
         <option value="2">R</option>
         <option value="3">P</option>
        </select>
       </div>

       <div class="box02">
        <div class="input-group ">
         <span
          class="input-group-addon btn-success"><i
          class="fa fa-money"></i></span> <input id="input-price"
          type="text" data-thousands="." data-decimal=","
          name="valueNegotiated"
          class="form-control" />
        </div>
       </div>


       <div class="box03">
        <textarea id="destination-observations" name="negociationObservations" rows="3" placeholder="Observações..." class="form-control"
         style="min-height: 130px;"></textarea>
       </div>


       <input type="hidden" name="csrf"
        value="EWRT565E6" />

      </div>

     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer clear" style="margin: 0px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
       data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      <button id="button-add-destination" type="button"
       class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```